# Binary Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller

We have the following code in Swift 3 no longer working but was working in previous version of Swift. In the line of code `array += [attributes]` we're getting error "Binary Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?". Any suggestions: Here is the code:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var array: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    for i in 0 ... max(0, numberOfItems - 1) {
        var indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
        var attributes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
        if attributes != nil {
            array += [attributes]
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: try using `array.append(attributes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
array.append(attributes)
```

instead of

```
array += [attributes]
```

Comment: I tried this approach. The compiler now throws out an error: fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type.

Comment: Also change `var array: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []` to `var array: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()`

Comment: This has worked. Thanks so much for support. Answer marked!

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

try using `array.append(attributes)`.
because to add something in an array, we use the `append` function

The +=operator works fine for `Int`, `Float`, `Double',`String` and other data types not for an array

Comment: I tried and still not working. I now get error "Value of optional type "UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?' not unwrapped".

Comment: do this array.append(attributes!)